# Cannot access enum before initialization, react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my program, I have lots of files with enum definitions like this and some files which join enums together. The enums are string-enums, so the indexing is not part of the problem. When I join enums together I get the error "Cannot access 'Both' before initialization". There are also circular imports, since I am using the combined enum in the first file. I understand the error message, however I import the files containing the necessary enums before defining 'Both'. Is this a typescript bug or am I missing something? I am using typescript in a React environment, so maybe I am missing the right tsconfig lines.

```
// firstFile.ts

export enum One
{
    A,
    B,
}

export enum Two
{
    C = 2,
    D,
}


// secondFile.ts, throws error

import { One, Two } from './firstFile';

export const Both = 
{
    ...One,
    ...Two,
}
```

Comment: try `import { One, Two } from './firstFile';`, Problem might be in a way how you import `'firstFile'`, because you are using absolute import instead of relative

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yes, I mistyped this. It is not my actual code, only for demonstration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circular dependencies are allowed in TypeScript (and ECMAScript as well), the **static resolution** of `import` and `export` clauses will work, but you have to be careful of the **execution order** of the files, depending on the entry point. Indeed, when a circular dependency is met, the entry point acts as the trunk of the dependency tree, so the other files execute before. When a file executes **all of its top-level code executes**, and will fail if it meets unresolved variables.

Now let's see what happens in your particular case. Your code transpiles to something like this:

**firstFile.ts**

```
import { Both } from "./secondFile.js";
export var One;
(function (One) {
    One[One["A"] = 0] = "A";
    One[One["B"] = 1] = "B";
})(One || (One = {}));
export var Two;
(function (Two) {
    Two[Two["C"] = 2] = "C";
    Two[Two["D"] = 3] = "D";
})(Two || (Two = {}));
```

**secondFile.ts**

```
import { One, Two } from './firstFile.js';
export const Both = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, One), Two);
```

If you use `secondFile.ts` as the entry point, `firstFile.ts` will execute first and will not throw any error because `Both` is unused in `firstFile.ts`.

However, if you add let's say a `console.log(Both.A)` at the end of `firstFile.ts` it will fail with a `Cannot access 'Both' before initialization` error because `secondFile.ts` has not executed yet, so `Both` is exported but not initialized.

Comment: I'll write this as a comment because it's my own opinion: circular dependencies increase the complexity of the code and makes the responsibility of each file unclear. I strongly suggest you to review your design in order to remove that circular dependency.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into refactoring my code to unwind the mess of imports.

Comment: In my case class B extended from class A and in class A I was using `instance of B` which caused the circular dependency